# How to get a object from array for a particular value

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

In swift i am using this code to get particular object for a particular value

```
if let layer = self.layers.first(where: {$0.id == id}) { }
```

I want to use this same in objective-c. How should i get a object from array of objects for particular value

Comment: what is `layer` here? Is it some kind of array of modal ?

Comment: yeah it is an array of modal

Comment: Added an answer.

Comment: I would recommend this lib https://github.com/google/functional-objc because Objective-C is missing real functional interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSPredicate` in `Objective-C` to filter an array.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", id];
id layer = [[self.layers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] firstObject]
```

Answer (score 1):

The predicateWithFormat solution is short, but not as type-safe as Swift.

To make it a bit more type-safe you could use [indexOfObjectPassingTest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1408043-indexofobjectpassingtest?language=objc).

Assuming you have:

```
@interface MyLayer
@property int layerID;
@end

NSArray<MyLayer *> *layers = @[...];
int layerIDToFind = 123;
```

You can write:

```
NSUInteger index = [layers indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(MyLayer *layer, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return layer.layerID == layerIDToFind;
}];
if (index != NSNotFound) {
    MyLayer *layer = layers[index];
    // ... act on the layer ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", id];

NSArray *result = [self.layers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

if result.count > 0
{
    id  layer = [result firstObject].id
}
```

Comment: how you get .id value from array "result".

Comment: i have change that